# Why do git merge removes code that needs to be in merged commit?

Tags: git, git-merge

Refering to the schema below from gitk, some lines of code added in commit `A` is not present in commit `D` or even `E`. Those lines of codes are in commit `B` or `C`.

Parent commit of `D` (the one with green line, 'remotes/origin/fl') has some indentation in the same file where those lines are missing.

Could someone explain how can this happen that the merge in `D` went without conflict on that file?

[image: Git schema]

Comment: Why do you think there wasn't conflict ? Perhaps the conflict was not fixed correctly

Comment: @Ôrel because I had that git console open and I saw auto merging in that file.

Comment: Are you using `git rerere` , this can explain what you have seen, there was a conflict but it was resolved as last time

Comment: No, I'm not using it. I just heard of it today that I was searching how this could happen.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're asking about how Git came up with a particular merge *result* in commit `D`, we need to look at the input graphs.

Commit `D` is the result of merging two commits: the one marked `B`—I think this is its first parent although I'm not sure that `gitk` uses the same rules as `git log --graph`—and the unmarked commit with the tag `remotes/origin/fl<blotted-out>`.  For reference below I'll call this commit `P`.  So if you want to know *why* Git produced what it did, you should run:

```
git merge-base --all <hash-of-B> <hash-of-P>
```

and see what commit hash IDs come up.

As I use my eyeball to walk the graph backwards from commit `B`, I find that commit `B` itself is a merge: it has, as its two parents, commit `A` and an unmarked commit with no log message.  As I use my eyeballs on commit `P`, it has as its single parent this same unmarked commit with no log message.  So this commit is probably the (single) merge base in question.  For reference below I'll call this commit `O`.

So, we have now found the merge base of commits `B` and `P`.  Using `git merge-base --all` to get Git to do it is better, but I believe this is commit `O`.  To see how Git will merge commits `B` and `P`, then, we run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-O> <hash-of-B>
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-O> <hash-of-P>
```

These two sets of diffs show which files are changed with respect to the shared merge-base commit, and what changes there are.  Git will then *combine* these changes, apply them to the snapshot in commit `O`, and—if there are no conflicts—go on to make merge commit `D`.

If there were options passed to `git merge`, or (as [Ôrel noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701907/why-do-git-merge-removes-code-that-needs-to-be-in-merged-commit#comment116167120_65701907)) you had `git rerere` enabled, that could affect the merge results.  Unfortunately when Git makes a merge commit, it does not include, in the merge commit's metadata, any of this information.

Comment: What does first parent mean? In the GUI at commit `D` I see hash of `B` with red and hash of `P` in blue... perhaps it shows that. You were right, result of `git merge-base --all <hash-of-B> <hash-of-P>` is the hash of commit `O`.  First diff shows the addition of the lines I want to be in commit `D` (those added in `A`) and second shows the indentation done. As I know `git rerere` should be activated as it is not enabled by default. Command was executed from VS code editor terminal, but I don't thinks this can make a difference. I believe that I should had conflict message, but I didn't get.

Comment: At this point can I use `cherry-pick` to take changes from commit `A`?

Comment: (1) "First" vs "second" parent doesn't matter for `git merge` unless you use `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs`, but is useful later with operations like `git log --first-parent`. The first parent of a merge is the commit you were on when you ran `git merge`.

Comment: (2) If the added lines are not "touching" the re-indented lines, there's no conflict, but if they do "touch" (overlap or butt up against each other) you should indeed get a conflict. Whether VS-code-editor obeys the same rules as Git, though, I have no idea. I avoid GUIs as much as possible as they tend to do weird and sometimes bad things without telling you they're doing that.

Comment: (3) Yes, you should be able to fix things up after-the-fact with a cherry-pick.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! I don't really know if I should mark this as an answer because I couldn't understand why that happened. However I voted up since it has a lot of useful information into it.